# How to select an "AS field" in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a Query which is separated in different parts. (distance, score and rank)

```
SELECT Entry.*, Address.*, 
(6367.41 * SQRT(2 * (1-cos(RADIANS(Entry.latitude)) * cos(0.92640848333131) * (sin(RADIANS(Entry.longitude)) * sin(0.15361853481704) + cos(RADIANS(Entry.longitude)) * cos(0.15361853481704)) - sin(RADIANS(Entry.latitude)) * sin(0.92640848333131)))) 
AS distance, 

(CASE WHEN `Entry`.`title` LIKE '%%' THEN 50 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN `Entry`.`description` LIKE '%%' THEN 30 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN `Entry`.`description_long` LIKE '%%' THEN 10 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN `Entry`.`product_type` = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN `Entry`.`product_type` = 2 THEN 40 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN `Entry`.`product_type` = 3 THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) 
AS score, 

(CASE WHEN (score > 100 AND distance <= 10) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
rank 

FROM `usr_web12_1`.`entries` AS `Entry` 
inner JOIN `usr_web12_1`.`entrieslocations` AS `Entrieslocation` ON (`Entry`.`id` = `Entrieslocation`.`entry_id`) 
inner JOIN `usr_web12_1`.`addresses` AS `Address` ON (`Address`.`id` = `Entry`.`address_id`) 
WHERE ((`Entry`.`title` LIKE '%%') OR (`Entry`.`description` LIKE '%%') OR (`Entry`.`description_long` LIKE '%%') OR (`Entry`.`meta_keywords` LIKE '%%') OR (`Entry`.`filter_keywords` LIKE '%%')) AND `Entry`.`status` = 1 AND 
`Entry`.`latitude` Between 52.179974594081 AND 53.978617805919 AND `Entry`.`longitude` Between 7.3045938084915 AND 10.298793591508 AND `Entrieslocation`.`category_id` = 1 
GROUP BY `Entry`.`id` 
ORDER BY `Entry`.`product_type` desc 
LIMIT 10
```

Question: The rank-part doesn't work "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'score' in 'field list'", **how can I access a dynamic AS-Field**???

Same problem with distance...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an aliased column name in the `select` or `where` clause.

You could use it later in the `group by`, `order by`, `having` clause. See [the MySQL doc for that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html).

Comment: Thanks, so I need to take the complete score-block as subquery and replace the score-part in rank? Other ideas?

Comment: Yes, you have to write the whole thing twice.

Comment: It works :) But how about performance, the complete query would take many pages... Does Mysql cache the results for each row, so that it calculates the distance for example only once?

Comment: Not sure if MySQL is smart enough. You can check it if you look at the `explain select ...` output doing it once and then twice. If they are the same, then it is cached.